# What's the best way to collect user testimonials on GitHub?

Tags: github

If I want to allow users to submit testimonials about a software project hosted on GitHub, what is the best way to collect user testimonials?

Ideas:

1. Open an issue, and link to the issue, letting users post their testimonial as a comment.
2. Create a `testimonials.md`, and let users contribute testimonials as pull requests.
3. Do something through the Wiki, which also involves pull requests.

I'm favouring 1.  What's the best method?  Surely someone else has done this already.

Comment: Create a github page presenting the project, providing documentation, examples, etc. Put the testimonals there.

Comment: Yes I have that, but I want users to be able to "submit" testimonials, without me having to collect them through some other means (such as email) and then have to update the project page myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done through pull-request, for contributing to the code (here a page `testimonials.md`)

A pull request allow the kind of review and discussion before accepting a new testimonial.

That approach is mentioned for instance in "[Using Gitbook to document an open source project](https://medium.com/@gpbl/how-to-use-gitbook-to-publish-docs-for-your-open-source-npm-packages-465dd8d5bfba#.e53waxxbt)", with markdown ebook written with [GitBook](https://www.gitbook.com/).

Comment: That was my 2nd option, and I probably agree with you. But I don't see any mention of this specifically in the GitBook link you supplied.

Comment: @KenBenoit The link mentions " Everyone can contribute to them with a simple pull request."

Comment: Thanks - I meant nothing specific to testimonials. From my question I hope it's clear I understand how pull requests work.